# API interface design - toggle or 2 different interfaces

Tags: api, interface, api-design

I am studying interface design.

Here is what I curious about.

- Some of open API support 2 different interfaces to implement toggling. i.e. instagram `like` interface. It separates like interface(like, cancel like)
- What is the advantage of separate those two.(separating into two interfaces makes end-user more complicated in my view)

I question this, since it could be implemented with toggle.

i.e. user send item_id and user_id. server check database(this item is already liked or not), and update.

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real benefit to having two interfaces for toggling is that it doesn't require the user to know the current state of the thing they are attempting to change (i.e. it doesn't require me to first query for the state).

If I am a consumer of an API, typically I will want to perform actions such as `like`-ing something. Very rarely can I think of a case where I would want to perform the action of `do the opposite of what I did previously` (unless I'm feeling like flip-flopping). If you didn't have two endpoints for `like` and `unlike` then you'd first have to poll the API to get the current status, and then perform the toggle that you're talking about if needed.

This situation introduces more logic into your code, requires that you make 1-2 calls to the API, and assumes that the state didn't change between calls; whereas having two endpoints reduces the logic, limits your API calls to 1 per action, and you don't have to worry about the state changing unexpectedly.

In the case where you try to `like` something that the user has already `like`d, then the API would simply return a successful result and not alter the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very convincing. However, I still got a question. I will apply to specific situation, like and cancel like. As an end-point user, if it uses separate API, I have to check the state of view every time. On the other hand, If it uses one toggling API, I will call same API without checking - maybe checking current status is not for end-user. (I premise that key of like api is user_id and media_id) Since this API tied with the specific user, I think I do not care about state changing. I still do not get the advantage separate APIs for some action like `like`. Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "check the state of view every time". You wouldn't have to do this because the API would accept your `like` action even if the item was already `like`d. It would silently not change the value. I have updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: I store instagram images in database(since, admin user want to filter some of hash tag results). Then a portal user came to the site and want to do `like` action. So he press like button(this button is design-toggle text switching between `like` and `cancel`). In this situation, developer has to check current button text and call instagram API, since `like` and `cancel like` are different. // This is what I meant in "check the state of view everytime". However I got your point

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One reason to prefer an interface where you specify the desired state explicitly is that it will be idempotent. That is, the resulting state is the same even if the request is made multiple times.

This is a pretty contrived example, but if two different people sharing the same account tried to like the same thing within a small enough window, you could end up with it being un-liked instead.